# android Sax parsing exception for "»" character

Tags: android, parsing, special-characters, sax

hi friends i'm using Sax parser for parsing my xml file which i recieve from the internet... The problem is that the normal xml is parsed fine except the xml files which have "»" symbol in the attributes...

everytime i try parsing the file i get the following error

```
02-11 16:57:35.547: INFO/System.out(754): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 9, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Is there any methid by which i can bypass this character ar handle it myself through java code??? Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode `»` as the XML entity `&#187;` instead.

Comment: got it Dav... Thanx a lot... actually got another html code too... but does this mean that there is no way we can handle it through code???

i mean my xml is prepared by the client... if he makes a mistake the app suffers... cant we handle it somehow???

Comment: hi..i need help on fixing same kind of issue in DOM feed parser,when i parse the xml content with Android's xml parsing with &#x2019,here i'm getting problem with parsing,DOM parser not parse this well,please help me